# $f(t) \in L^k$ implies $f(t) \ll t^{-1/k - \epsilon}$?

Tags: real-analysis

If a function $f$ is an $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$-function, then by definition,
\[
\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f|^{2}.
\]

I am wonrdering if we can say anything specific about the decreasing order
of $f$ as $|t| \to \infty$?

If $f$ is an $L^{2}$-function, then it is not unnatural to guess that
\[
f(t) \ll |t|^{-1/2 - \epsilon}, \epsilon > 0.
\]

Thanks.

Comment: Not a chance. You can ride some triangles out to infinity with heights as tall as you want, as long as the bases are small enough.

Comment: Physicists like to claim that this is true. It is not remotely true. Even easier than triangles, consider Riemann rectangles centered at the integers where the base is very narrow and the height grows at a slower rate.